# What are the characters printed when Alt+Arrow keys are pressed?

Tags: command-line, terminal, key-mapping

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>, `A` printed to terminal screen. Same thing happened when I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> but `B` is printed instead.

Other characters that I realized;

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> = `D` and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> = `C`

What is the purpose of these commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on how the terminal is configured, typing <kbd>Alt+Key</kbd> is like typing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Key</kbd> keys in sequence, so it sends the ESC character (aka `\e` or `^[` or `\033`) followed by the character or sequence of characters sent upon pressing that <kbd>Key</kbd>.

Upon pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>, most terminal emulators send either the three characters `\033[A` or `\033OA` depending on whether they're in application keypad mode or not.

The first one does correspond to the escape sequence which when output to the terminal, move the cursor up. If you do:

```
printf '\nfoo\033[Abar\n\n'
```

You'll see `bar` written after `foo` one row up. If you do:

```
stty -echoctl; tput rmkx; read foo
```

You'll see that the arrow keys do move the cursor around.

When an application like `zsh` or `vi` reads that sequence of characters from the terminal, it interprets it as the "Up" action, because it knows from the terminfo database (`kcuu1` capability) that it is the escape sequence sent upon pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>.

Now, for <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd>, some terminals like `rxvt` and its derivatives like `eterm` send `\033` followed by the escape sequence for <kbd>Up</kbd> (that is `\033\033[A` or `\033\033OA`), while some others like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` have separate escape sequences for those types of keys when used with the combination keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Those will typically send `\033[1;3A` upon <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd>.

When sent to the terminal, that sequence will also move the cursor up (the second parameter (3) is ignored). There's no corresponding *keypad* key, so it's the same sequence sent upon <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd> in or out of *application keypad mode*.

Now  whether it's `\033\033[A` or `\033[1;3A`, many applications don't know what those sequences are for. The terminfo database won't help them, because there's no such capability that defines what characters those key combinations send.

They will try their best to interpret that sequence. `bash` for instance will interpret `\033[1;3` as an escape sequence, doesn't know anything about it, so does nothing, followed by `A`. `zsh`, will stop reading as soon as it finds out there's no known matching character sequence. There's no escape sequence that it knows that starts with `\033[1` so it will skip that, and read the rest: `;3A` and insert that in the line editor.

Many applications like `vi`, `zsh` or `readline` based ones like `gdb` or `bash` (though beware `bash` uses a modified version of `readline`) allow you to add bindings for any sequence of characters.

For instance, in `zsh`, you may want to bind <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd>, <kbd>Alt-Down</kbd> like:

```
bindkey '\e[1;3A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[1;3B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

Those are to search the history backward and forward for command lines that start like the current one up to the current position of the cursor which is quite handy to recall previous commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to return input codes of your keyboard. If you do that for arrow keys, you will get `[[D^`, `[[C^`, `[[A^`, and `[[B` values. There aren't any default bindings for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrow keys, so it seems that performed action is printing letter code alone. Hovewer, if you create your local version of readline library configuration file:

```
$ cp /etc/inputrc ~/.inputrc
```

And add a line:

```
"\e[1;3C": "sometexthere"
```

Where `[1;3C` is input code of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (you can get it same way as before using <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> shortcut) and restart your terminal then <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> shortcut will return you text "sometexthere" and other <kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrow shortcuts will stop returning characters.

Instead text you can pass a bindable command from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands like

```
"\e[1;3C": unix-line-discard
```

to have same effect like <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (delete line).

More information here: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is often used as a *meta* modifier.  Cursor- and function-keys are referred to as *special keys* since they may send multiple characters — and the characters which are sent can be altered.

Some users, e.g., for `bash` expect that pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> will send a key prefixed by the escape character.  The documented "meta" feature (see [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous)) deals with the eighth bit:

> If the terminal has a "meta key" which  acts  as  a  shift
>   key,  setting  the  8th  bit of any character transmitted,
>   this fact can be indicated with **`km`**.   Otherwise,  software
>   will assume that the 8th bit is parity and it will usually
>   be cleared.  If strings exist to turn this *"meta mode"*  on
>   and off, they can be given as **`smm`** and **`rmm`**.

`bash` knows about that, too (see [ncurses FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode)), but few of its users are interested in the feature.  Nonetheless, they're accustomed to referring to <kbd>Alt</kbd> as "meta", even though meta mode is turned off.  Both rxvt and xterm have had this feature since (at least) the early 1990s.

Other users (since `xterm` introduced the feature in [patch #94, 1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_94)) may expect the modifier information to be encoded as a parameter in the sequence of characters that a special key would send.  XTerm's documentation referred to these modified keys as ["PC-style"](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys) function keys to distinguish them from ["VT220-style"](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-VT220-Style-Function-Keys) (which did not have modifiers).  An unmodified cursor key might send <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, but it is also legal to have a *parameter*, e.g., <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, which an application *should* understand as repeating that five times.  The first version of `xterm`'s *PC-style* keys used that "5" to denote <kbd>control</kbd>, and a later version changed it to avoid confusion with the repeat count.  So...

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

suggests that the application move the cursor up 5 rows, while

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

suggests that it move up one row, telling the application that a <kbd>control</kbd> key was pressed.

The useful combinations have been in the ncurses terminfo database since [2004](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20040717):

```
# 2004-07-17
#       * add xterm-pc-fkeys -TD
```

The terminfo database shows the current version of [xterm+pcfkeys](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_pcfkeys) with a comment showing how the modifiers are encoded:

```
# This fragment describes as much of XFree86 xterm's "pc-style" function
# keys as will fit into terminfo's 60 function keys.
# From ctlseqs.ms:
#    Code     Modifiers
#  ---------------------------------
#     2       Shift
#     3       Alt
#     4       Shift + Alt
#     5       Control
#     6       Shift + Control
#     7       Alt + Control
#     8       Shift + Alt + Control
#  ---------------------------------
# The meta key may also be used as a modifier in this scheme, adding another
# bit to the parameter.
```

(Alt and meta are not necessarily the same key).  That is a *building block* (in turn composed of other building blocks) from which the [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm) terminal description is formed.  It uses an extension provided in ncurses [since 1999](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t990301) which allows user-defined names.  Since termcap supports only 2-character names, and 1023-byte descriptions, there was no reason to make these extended names available through the *termcap* interface.  They're readily available to applications using the *terminfo* interface.

Now comes a difficulty: there are a few ways for an application to determine what a key sequence like that represents:

1. analyze the sequence of characters completely
2. partly analyze it and throw away the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier if not needed
3. just compare the sequence of characters against a dictionary, hoping to determine the meaning that way.

Few programs would do the first; some text editors would do the second (actually, I did *this* for [**`ded`**](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html) in the [late 1980s](http://invisible-island.net/ded/td_lib/CHANGES.html#t19890731)).  Developers for applications such as `bash` chose the third route by assuming that most of the information is in *termcap*.  Alternatively, they could have chosen to make a table with termcap/terminfo information and use the interface which gave the best information.  `xterm` does this for the [*tcap-query*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_148) feature, providing `vim` with the actual function key assignments.

Since none of the strings that `bash` compares against match the strings it receives, it can get confused, settling for partial matches (such as the escape character by itself).

Further reading:

- [How to fix the shifted function keys in vim in xterm in gnome-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58361/how-to-fix-the-shifted-function-keys-in-vim-in-xterm-in-gnome-terminal/272526#272526)